# cancancan row based filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, cancancan

I have declared a role ability in the cancancan gem (rails 5, postgres, devise):

```
can [:update, :show, :destroy, :index], SalesDatum do |datum|
  datum.try(:user_id) == user.id #the ids just access the id's from the user object that is passed into can can and from the table
end
```

`SalesDatum` has a `user_id` field.

This works on the show actions, because I can only `show` the SalesDatum that has the logged in `user_id` For example:

http://localhost:8080/projects/19/sales_data/961
correctly gets authenticated because the logged in user_id matches the user_id on the sales_data

http://localhost:8080/projects/19/sales_data/800
correctly does not get authenticated because the logged in user_id does not match the user_id on the sales_data

However when I go to the get index action:
http://localhost:8080/projects/19/sales_data
it shows all of the sales data from the `@sales_data` variable. So, it would show the data.id 800 and 961.

sales data controller:

```
load_and_authorize_resource
def index
  @sales_data = SalesDatum.where(project_id:params[:project_id])
end
```

How do I get the index action to only show the data with the relevant user_id? Isn't cancan supposed to filter that according to the `user_id`?

Comment: I can edit the controller query to `SalesDatum.where(project_id:params[:project_id]).where(user_id:`current_user.id`)` but that seems like a really poor way of authenticating?

Comment: This is really why I have abandoned CanCanCan in favour of Pundit - the deceptively simple DSL does not do very well at defining authentication scopes or handling anything non-trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the rule with the hash syntax.

```
can [:update, :show, :destroy, :index], SalesDatum, user_id: user.id
```

you may also want to define the `edit` action and therefore:

```
can [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy, :index], SalesDatum, user_id: user.id
```

which can be simplified into:

```
can :manage, SalesDatum, user_id: user.id
```

if SalesDatum has a `belongs_to :user` defined you can also write:

```
can :manage, SalesDatum, user: user
```

Comment: This is great, is there not a good way to do this with the block syntax?

Comment: Block syntax should always be the last choice because it  works only on the instance and not the collection. For collections you need to use hash syntax.